# Dominant contribution from $\int_1^\infty x^a (x-1)^b e^{cx}\ dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals, asymptotics, approximation

For real $a\gg0$, $b\gg0$, $c<0$, I want to know if the dominant contribution from the integral,
$$\int_1^\infty x^a (x-1)^b e^{cx}\ dx=\int_1^\infty\exp\left(a\log x+b\log(x-1)+cx\right)\ dx$$
is
$$\int_{T-\epsilon}^{T+\epsilon}x^a(x-1)^be^{cx}\ dx=\int_{T-\epsilon}^{T+\epsilon}\exp\left(a\log x+b\log(x-1)+cx\right)\ dx$$
where $T$ solves the derivative of the exponent,
$$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x-1}+c=0.$$

---

I assumed this was true and tried building an asymptotic approximation for large $T$.

Let $u=x-T$,
$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(a\log(u+T)+b\log(u+T-1)+c(u+T)\right)\ du$$
note that when $u$ is close to $0$,
$$a\log(u+T)+b\log(u+T-1)+c(u+T)\sim a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT+\left(\frac{a}{T}+\frac{b}{T-1}+c\right)u+O\left(u^2\right)$$
keeping the first non-constant term and expanding the terms beyond it by its Maclaurin series,
$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp \left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT+\left(\frac{a}{T}+\frac{b}{T-1}+c\right)u\right)\left(1+O\left(u^2\right)\right)\ du$$
hence the leading approximation is,
$$\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right)\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(\left(\frac{a}{T}+\frac{b}{T-1}+c\right)u\right)\ du$$
normally at this step I would replace the end points of the integral with $-\infty$ and $\infty$, but here I get a divergent result. Does this mean that the terms I'm introducing are not subdominant, i.e., my initial assumption of rewriting as $\int_{T-\epsilon}^{T+\epsilon}$ is incorrect?

Comment: `a \gg 0` gives $a \gg 0$

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the issue. The coefficient of the $u^1$ term was $0$ by the definition of $T$, so taking one more term should resolve the issue.
$$a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT-\left(\frac{a}{T^2}+\frac{b}{(T-1)^2}\right)\frac{u^2}{2}+O\left(u^3\right)$$
this time properly keeping the first non-constant term,
$$\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right)\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\exp{\left(-\left(\frac{a}{T^2}+\frac{b}{(T-1)^2}\right)\frac{u^2}{2}\right)}\left(1+O\left(u^3\right)\right)\ du$$
hence the leading order,
$$\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{\left(-\left(\frac{a}{T^2}+\frac{b}{(T-1)^2}\right)\frac{u^2}{2}\right)}\ du$$
where we also replaced the endpoints of the integral. Rewrite the integrand as $\exp(-ku^2/2)$ and note that it is even,
$$2\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right)\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{ku^2}{2}\right)\ du$$
with
$$k:=\frac{a}{T^2}+\frac{b}{(T-1)^2}$$
perform a change of variables from $u$ to $s$ via $s^2=ku^2/2$,
$$2\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}}\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right)\int_0^\infty\exp \left(-s^2\right)\ ds$$
hence by the Gaussian integral,
$$\begin{align*}\int_1^\infty x^a (x-1)^b e^{cx}\ dx&\sim\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{k}}\exp\left(a\log(T)+b\log(T-1)+cT\right) \\&=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{k}}T^a(T-1)^be^{cT}\end{align*}$$
as $T\to\infty$. Some simplifications with $k$ may be possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Just a few ideas.*

May be, you could consider the two (limiting ?) cases
$$I_1=\int_1^\infty x^a\, x^b \, e^{cx},\,dx=E_{-(a+b)}(-c)$$
$$I_2=\int_1^\infty (x-1)^a\, (x-1)^b \, e^{cx}\,dx= \frac{e^c\,\,\Gamma (a+b+1)}{(-c)^{(a+b+1)}}$$ or, even, for an appropriate value of  $k \in (0,1)$
$$I_3=\int_1^\infty (x-k)^a\, (x-k)^b \, e^{cx}\,dx=\frac{ e^{c k} \,\,\Gamma (a+b+1,-c (1-k))}{(-c)^{(a+b+1)}}$$ which simplifies the problem from $3$D to $2$D.

Also, notice that
$$I_4=\int_1^\infty x^\alpha\, (x-1)^\alpha \, e^{cx}\,dx=\frac{e^{c/2}\,\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{(-c)^{\frac{2\alpha+1}{2}}\sqrt{\pi }}K_{\frac{2\alpha+1}{2}}\left(-\frac{c}{2}\right)$$

Now, consider the behaviour of $(I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4)$ on a logarithmic scale.