# Laplace's method on $\int_0^\infty x^m\exp \left( - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right)\ dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, asymptotics, approximation, laplace-method

I was looking to approximate [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765802/a-tight-upper-bound-for-gaussian-integral) integral using ideas from Laplace's method, however I ended up with a $\color{red}{\text{divergent improper integral}}$. I want to know why such a method doesn't work in this case. I suspect it is because of how I define $k$ which might be interfering with the approximations.

For $\mu,\sigma>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{R}$
$$I=\int_0^\infty x^m\exp \left( - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right)\ dx$$
my attempt is below.

---

The integrand is,
$$
x^m\exp \left( - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right)=\exp\left(m\log x-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$
which obtains its maximum value when the derivative of the exponent is $0$,
$$\frac{m}{x}-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{\mu+\sqrt{\mu^2+4\sigma m}}{2}$$
call the point $k$, then we have,
$$\begin{align*}
I&\sim\int_{k-\epsilon}^{k+\epsilon}\exp\left(m\log x-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\ dx \\
&=\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(m\log(t+k)-\frac{(t+k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\ dt
\end{align*}$$
where we substituted $t=x-k$. By Taylor's formula,
$$m\log(t+k)-\frac{(t+k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\sim m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}\right)t+O(t^2)$$
when $t$ is in the neighborhood of $0$ (note that the first term is a constant). Keeping the first *non-constant* term, and exponentiating the rest via the Maclaurin series,
$$\begin{align*}&\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}\right)t\right)(1+O(t^2))\ dt\\
\sim&\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}\right)t\right)\ dt \\
=&k^m\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\exp\left(\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}\right)t\right)\ dt. \\
\end{align*}$$
Now changing the end points to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ only adds a subdominant function,
$$k^m\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\color{red}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}\right)t\right)\ dt}$$
however here,
$$\frac{m}{k}-\frac{\mu-k}{\sigma^2}=\frac{m\sigma^2-uk+k^2}{k\sigma^2}=\frac{m\sigma^2+k^2}{k\sigma^2}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$$
with
$$k:=\frac{\mu+\sqrt{\mu^2+4\sigma m}}{2}$$
seems to be positive for any $\mu,\sigma>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{R}$; this means the $\color{red}{\text{integral}}$ is divergent.

Comment: There is a sign error in the power series expansion of $f(t):=m\log(t+k)-\frac{(t+k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$. The correct result is
$$
f(t)=m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{k-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right)t-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2+O(t^3).
$$
The coefficient of $t$ is zero, and the $\color{red}{\text{red integral}}$ should be replaced with
$$
\color{red}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2\right)dt,}
$$
which is finite.

Comment: @Gonçalo. Thank you for helping me find the error. I can't believe I made the same mistake as here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764945/1141581) again. It seems like the $t^1$ term always terminates, do you know anything about it?

Comment: You are doing an expansion around the *minimum* of the exponent $f(x)$; at that point, the first derivative $f'(x)$ vanishes.

Comment: @Gonçalo. Makes sense. Does my work below look correct?

Comment: Why have you "deleted" the term $-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ in Taylor's formula? It contributes with a factor $\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ to the integral.

Comment: @Gonçalo. Oops. That is a genuine mistake, I meant to keep that.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gonçalo pointed out, the coefficient of $t^1$ was zero by the definition of $k$, so taking one more term in the expansion should resolve the issue.

By Taylor's formula,

$$\begin{align*}m\log(t+k)-\frac{(t+k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}&\sim m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\left(\frac{m}{k}-\frac{k-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right)t-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2+O(t^3) \\
&=m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2+O(t^3) 
\end{align*}$$
in the neighborhood of $t=0$. Keeping the first *non-constant* term and exponentiating the rest via the Maclaurin series,
$$\begin{align*}I&\sim\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \exp\left(m\log k-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2\right)(1+O(t^3))\ dt \\
&\sim k^m\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\exp\left(-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2\right)\ dt \\
&\sim k^m\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\color{navy}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2\right)\ dt} \\
&=2k^m\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_{0}^\infty\exp\left(-\left(\frac{m}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)t^2\right)\ dt
\end{align*}$$
note that the $\color{navy}{\text{integral}}$ is happily finite. Make a change of variables from $t$ to $s$ via,
$$t=\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{2k^2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}}},\quad dt=\frac{ds}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{2k^2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}}}$$
we find
$$I\sim\frac{2k^m}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{2k^2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_{0}^\infty\exp(-s^2)\ ds$$
hence by the Gaussian integral,
$$I\sim \frac{k^m\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{2k^2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
for large $k$.